# Wait for inner functions to wait and execute then proceed execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am executing a cloud function which is written in nodeJS.Here the function triggers when a data from the external source comes in and in this function, I have to call and check DB at the particular table but it takes more than 5 seconds and before the execution of my `getDataFromDb` function my main function completed execution. Plus there is a function called `updateItems(postdate);` and it executes if I cannot find data in my DB when triggering `getDataFromDb`

I tried async await but I am not sure where I am doing wrong. my function always ends first before my DB operation ends.

```
  exports.handler = (event, context) => {

   //here i am making data ready for DB and checking for the record if that is present in db
        getDataFromDb(uniqueArray);

        function getDataFromDb(uniqueArray) {
          var params = {
            // params for get reques
          }
          //db get operation

          db.get(params, function (err, data) {
            //takes time here
            if (err) {
              console.log(err); // an error occurred
            }
            else {
             //another DB operation updateItems(postdata);
             //takes time here
              }
              else {
                console.log("first run for db")
                //another DB operation updateItems(postdata);
                //takes time here
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
      console.log("main function ended")
    };
```

the expected result should wait for the inner function to execute then end the main function but actually, the main function ends first then DB calling function ends

Comment: yeah... that's just how javascript works. the main thread doesn't wait for asynchronous actions to finish before continuing.

Comment: @KevinB so is there any fix to wait for dboperation functions  executions??

Comment: No. just code around it. Use callbacks, promises, etc

Comment: @kevinB Can you show me how to implement callback here

Answer (score 0):

Though this can be achieved through callbacks, converting it to promise chain makes it easy, as execution of inner function depends on outer function, it's better to chain promises i.e. return Promise in the call back of first function, to execute them serially.

```
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  getDataFromDb(uniqueArray).then(success => {
    console.log('Done')
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('handle get or post err here');
  });

  function getDataFromDb(uniqueArray) {
    var params = {};
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.get(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err); // an error occurred
        } else {
          return resolve(data);
        }
      });
    }).then(success => updateItems(data))
  }
});
```